# Fix build dependencies in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio-2013, build, build-dependencies

Let's assume we have a project `P1` and `P2` which do **not** reference each other. Both projects are referenced in two solutions and in happens that `P2` is built after `P1`.

Now if I add a dependency to a projeckt `P2` in one solution, the build dependency in that solution will be perfectly fine (`P2` will now be built before `P1`), but the other one will miss that dependency update and the solution does not update itself.

Does someone know a "tool" to fix the build dependency based on the current project dependencies?